# Why i can not find value is numeric conditional in dqs domain rule?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm beginner in `Sql server Data quality services` and for that purpose read this tutorial from microsoft MSDN site:
[Create a Domain Rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510397.aspx)

But in the my data quality can not find value is numeric condition in domain build rule,what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks for all.

Comment: Can you maybe get a native English speaker to help you re-word your question?   It doesn't make any sense as written.

Comment: So you are stating that the "Value IS Numeric" rule condition is missing or you don't know where to find it when creating a new DQS rule.  Sorry my DQS dev environment is down right now, but hopefully someone will be able to help you out.