# How can i write regular expression to check is numeric in DQS domain rule?

Tags: ssis, data-quality-services

I'm new in `ssis` and `dqs` ,i want use the dqs to check is data numeric or no,for that purpose in the dqs client,define numeric domain and in the domain define rule with this image:
[image]

for example i check this number:

```
125a2sd56
```

that rule return to me that is numeric!,but `a` char or `sd` char into that and that is not numeric,what happen?is my expression is incorrect?how can i solve that problem?thank all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why i can not find value is numeric conditional in dqs domain rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990258/why-i-can-not-find-value-is-numeric-conditional-in-dqs-domain-rule)